# Problems with right text margin in user-defined beamer class

Tags: beamer, document-classes

I started to rebuild the cooperate design of my research group (designed in powerpoint) with an own document class based on the beamer package itself. Basically, I managed to get everything transfered, but I've some troubles with the right text margin. Currently, it seems as if my definition of the right text margin is ignored. I used `\setbeamersize{text margin left=15pt, text margin right=15pt}` and whenever I change the left margin I see an effect, but regardless of what I'm defining for the right margin, my frame contents (frame title, block environment, etc.) are running out of the frames :( In addition contents centered with the center environment, are not centered, but shifted a bit to the right. If I use the flushright environment, the content is placed outside the frame, too.

I'd be very happy for any advise or idea!

**@edit**
Thanks for your replies :) I found the problematic line: `\setlength\textwidth{0.9\paperwidth}`, after adding the 0.9 the content is not running out of the page anymore. One question I do still have: Would you suggest me to define rather a style sheet than a document class to provide our cooperate design? Depending on our different working groups the logo is slightly different and needs to be adapted... I thought about using a class-option for the selection of the appropriate logo version.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you create a complete, compilable example demonstrating the problem? (Edit: I realise this can be some work with a custom class, but try removing/commenting out modifications from the class or preamble and see if you can figure out exactly which part of the code that causes the problem.)

Comment: It seems as if something else in your custom class is affecting the page layout, and without seeing some actual code it will be really hard (if not impossible) to provide help. Please do as ** Torbjørn T.** suggested and try to reduce the problematic class code to a minimla version reproducing the problem; you can then add this as an edit to your question.

Comment: Welcome to the [TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Minimal working example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)) would be welcome, could you please add source code to your post by editing the post?

Comment: Defining a custom style sheet can also be done with options for different logos etc. So this criterion does not solve the question whether to use a style or a class.